# The difference between the number of params of LSTM and CuDNNLSTM in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

If an input dimension is 26 and the cell size is 100, the number of parameters in a bi-directional CTC network is 101,600.
When using Keras, I confirmed the number of parameters of a bi-directional LSTM layer was exactly the same as what I expected.
However, CuDNNLSTM contains 102,400 parameters.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide a clue about the 800 parameters for a quick understanding before reviewing the source code.

Comment: can you provide the model summary and the layer details for both.

Comment: [Why CuDNNLSTM has more parameres than LSTM in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384445/14290681) may answer your query. Thanks!